# How to fix Fail to connect to camera service on android?

Tags: android, camera

my app occur `Fail to connect to camera service` error.

because, I intentionally disconnect my camera.

this problem. if users intentionally disconnect camera. occur `Fail to connect to camera service` and app is die.

I want if camera disconnect, app not die.

my source

```
private static Camera mCamera = null;

if (mCamera == null) {
    mCamera = Camera.open(0);
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.lock();
    }
} ...
```

How to avoid camera opening when camera is not connected?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `android.hardware.Camera` was deprecated in API level 21. You should use `android.hardware.camera2` instead if you targeting API level 21 or above.

`Camera.open(0)` throw exception if opening the camera fails but noth returning null. See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open(int)) for more details. So, you need to catch exception instead of checking null.

```
if (mCamera == null) {
    try {       
        mCamera = Camera.open(0);
        mCamera.lock();
        ...
    } catch(RuntimeException e) {
        // opening the camera fails
    }
} ...
```